# What does setTimeout return?

Tags: javascript

I was curious that what does setTimeout return. So I did a quick test:

```
var thing = setTimeout(function(){},1);
```

And what surprise me is that it gave me a number. `1351` Each time is different.

So is it really all it returns is a number? So I can actually do this as well?

```
clearTimeout(1351);
```

Very confusing...

Comment: Its the timer ID handle : http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#timers

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's a handle (a unique identifier). When you create a timeout, the JavaScript runtime associates a handle with the timeout you created, and it can identify that timeout by the handle `setTimeout()` returns. When you run `clearTimeout()`, it will know what timeout you're talking about by looking at the unique handle you pass in.

Answer (score 16):

It can be an `Object`, I tested it with `node.js`:

```
var sto = setTimeout(
    function(){console.log('ping');}, 
    1000
);

console.log(sto);
```

The output is:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev:
   { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 1000 },
  _idleNext:
   { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 1000 },
  _idleStart: 2413359232,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _repeat: false,
  domain:
   { domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

Comment: As @Andrew_1510 said, in Nodejs it returns a Timeout object instead of an ID. This is useful to know as the majority of implementations of `setTimeout` return an ID and not a Timeout object like Nodejs, which may catch some people off guard.

As of writing this, it looks like NodeJS is the only one that returns an object instead of an ID according to the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 14):

You can think of it as a `timerID`, which uniquely identify a timer, so that you can reset by `clearTimeout(timerID)`

Answer (score 1):

it's a task ID (I prefer to think it's a task_ID rather than a Timeout_ID that confuses everyone).

imagine you have to launch a default function :  "f_cup_of_tea", that any normal individual would end up needing after 5 minutes on your website. :

```
tea_Task_ID = window.setTimeout(f_cup_of_tea, (5*60*1000), 15, 2);
```

like:
    function f_cup_of_tea(milk_ml, sugar) { .... }

but unfortunatly, with ten second late, a psychadelic user prefer to get something different than the entire world, and choose a bad_tequila...

you must cancel the delicious " f_cup_of_tea " scheduled within five minutes ...
fortunately javascript have thinking of this kind of problem and you can use :

```
window.clearTimeout(tea_Task_ID);
```

(but it woorks only if " f_cup_of_tea " are not yet started).

next,  you can launch :

```
tequila_Task_ID = window.setTimeout(f_bad_tequila, (5*1000), 0);  // for in 5s, with zero ice...
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you should be very careful clearing a timeout hat way, because that number could change in some situation. for example if you add another timeout somewhere in your code (accidentally before this one ( 1351) this id would change probably to 1352. so your clear Timeout would clear a different timeout.
the best way is to use a variable;

```
let test = "set_Timeout(() => {
    alert("hi")
}, 3000);

clear_Timeout(test);
```