# After clearTimeout it's still a number

Tags: javascript

I was a looking for a valid way to check if timeout still exists in order to clear it before. But realised it's `number` all the time at least in latest `Chrome` and `Safari`. I will appreciate a lot if somebody could shine some line on this case:

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  // do magic
}, 100000)

console.log(typeof timeout) // number (makes sense)

clearTimeout(timeout)
console.log(typeof timeout) // number (...hmm)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(typeof timeout) // number --> magic ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}, 1000)
```

Comment: FWIW calling clearTimeout on one that doesn't exist doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: Why you want to check if it hasn't been cancelled before? calling clearTimeout won't cause any error even if the timer stopped before.

Comment: @E.Omar since in my business logic clearing timeout attached as a simple hook on the logic that can be executed pretty frequently. Something deeps inside tells me that checking for timeout if it's exists is "cheaper" then just trying to clear it all the time

Comment: For people who are interested why assigning timer to variable always returns number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068981/what-does-settimeout-return/19375604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clearTimeout` does remove the callback from the timer queue. It does not alter the `timeout` variable that you used to store the identifier value - especially since you declared it as `const`.

> I was a looking for a valid way to check if timeout still exists

Use `let timeout` and set it to `null` or `undefined` when you clear it.

> in order to clear it before

or just *always* call `clearTimeout`, it doesn't do any harm if the timer has already been cleared before or did run.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting `timeout` to `undefined` when you clear it (and possibly when the timeout runs, depending on your usecase):

```
 clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = undefined;
```

That way you can then easily check if the timeout is done with

```
  if(timeout) /* do stuff */
```

(You have to change `const timeout` to `let timeout` then)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` (also `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`) return number with id of process so you can cancel it later. So when you call `clearTimeout(id)` process is cancelled. But primitive values, amont which there is number, are copied so once you assigned the number to variable, it stays there.

Calling `cleatTimeout(id)` for process that has been already cancelled doesn’t cause any error.